# Create table and insert rows if doesn't exist, else just insert

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert, insert-update

I am able to create table, shred JSON and add data if it does not exist in SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max);

SET @json = N'[{"IplayerName": "Pilipiliz",
                 "Sname": "kikombe",
                 "WeightLBs":"60.236"
               }]'

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE OBJECT_ID = object_id('Iplayerds')) 
BEGIN
    SELECT
        [IplayerName],
        [Sname],
        [WeightLBs]
    INTO
        Iplayerds
    FROM
        OPENJSON(@json) 
        WITH (IplayerName NVARCHAR(200),
              Sname NVARCHAR(20),
              WeightLBs DECIMAL(10,4)
             )
END
ELSE
    PRINT 'exists'
```

However, when I try to replace the print statement with insert rows code shown below, it fails

```
INSERT INTO Iplayerds (IplayerName, Sname, WeightLBs)
VALUES ([IplayerName], [Sname], [WeightLBs]
FROM OPENJSON(@json))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Dale K `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 38
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 40
Incorrect syntax near ')'.` Will add image where error occurs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `INSERT` command comes in two flavors:

**(1)** either you have all your values available, as literals or SQL Server variables - in that case, you can use the `INSERT .. VALUES()` approach:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Iplayerds (IplayerName, Sname, WeightLBs)
VALUES (@IplayerName, @Sname, @WeightLBs)
```

Note: I would recommend to **always** explicitly specify the list of column to insert data into - that way, you won't have any nasty surprises if suddenly your table has an extra column, or if your tables has an `IDENTITY` or computed column. Yes - it's a tiny bit more work - **once** - but then you have your `INSERT` statement as solid as it can be and you won't have to constantly fiddle around with it if your table changes.

**(2)** if you **don't** have all your values as literals and/or variables, but instead you want to rely on another table, multiple tables, or views, to provide the values, then you can use the `INSERT ... SELECT ...` approach:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Iplayerds (IplayerName, Sname, WeightLBs)
   SELECT
       [IplayerName], [Sname], [WeightLBs]
   FROM 
       OPENJSON(@json) WITH (IplayerName NVARCHAR(200),
                             Sname NVARCHAR(20),
                             WeightLBs DECIMAL(10,4)
                            )
```

Here, you must define exactly as many items in the `SELECT` as your `INSERT` expects - and those can be columns from the table(s) (or view(s)), or those can be literals or variables. Again: explicitly provide the list of columns to insert into - see above.

You can use **one or the other** - but you **cannot** mix the two - you cannot use `VALUES(...)` and then have a `SELECT` query in the middle of your list of values - pick one of the two - stick with it.